# Unable to convert to GPT to install Windows 10 home

Tags: windows, partitioning, gpt, diskpart, nvme

So first I did a factory reset once installing my NVME M.2, and that's when Windows had the first issue of not running. So I tried installing a fresh windows 10.

When trying to make a save location for Windows I tried to put it my NVME, however I was given the "cannot install as Efi disks have to be GPT", I was rather confused as this also applied to my hard drives which were able to run it earlier.

So I did a little digging around and tried to convert then to gpt through command line, however that only gave me the error "cannot convert cd-rom/dvd into gpt", when my case can't even have either of those two.

Then I thought, maybe the disks just don't have an EFI partition, so I tried to create a efi partition of size 5000, however then was given the error that the disk has "No usable free extent could be found". The NVME has a space of 1.8TB currently.

So now I'm stuck on how to install windows even though I never needed GPT, but now for some reason need it.

Specs if needed:
--- B450 tomahawk max
--- gtx 1050 ti
--- and a ryzen cpu, can't currently remember which one.

Comment: if you don't have any data to keep then just remove all the partitions and select create partition again, Windows will automatically create the appropriate ESP

Comment: Do you know the command in command line to do this?

Comment: I've deleted a 269gb partition and tried creating a EFI partition, however was given a "efi partitions are only supported on GPT disks", I tried converting the nvme to gpt however it still keeps saying that "cd-rom/dvd disks cannot be converted to gpt", the nvme isn't a disk drive.

Comment: Delete all partitions on the disk, then with legacy mode disabled, boot to the Windows installation environment and install Windows.  Your disk should be 100% unallocated

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data that you need to save on the NVMe drive then just use the Windows 10 installation USB to fully format the drive.

When you get to the first step of the installation that asks what type of installation you would like choose the bottom option (Customize).

Delete all partitions until there is only one. It should say "unallocated space".

Doing this will cause the installation to recreate all the proper partitions with the proper formats that you need.

If you have other drives connected you will not want to delete their partitions and I suggest that you remove/disconnect them until you get windows installed so you don't risk choosing the wrong partitions to delete during the 'custom installation'.